# Html elements into an array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have unlimited number of

```
<div class="item-1">text</div>
<div class="item-2">text</div>
<div class="item-3">text</div>
<div class="item-4">text</div>
<div class="item-5">text</div>
...
```

I want to search for all the available `div` and store them in an array with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wild card, starts with [**selector**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
arr = $('[class^=item-]');
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afsBx/1/)**

```
arr = $('[class^=item-]');

arr.each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to access them later to compare them with other functions. is it possible to do it??

Comment: I have added a demo which access each of them.